# Run adb logcat in the background without WiFi and USB

Tags: android, logcat

I have an application that uses both the USB and WiFi interface. I am currently debugging an issue where I have to use both the phone's USB and WiFi, and it switches between WiFi networks. This renders both USB and WiFi debugging useless.

Is there a way I could start `adb logcat` to run as a background process, do everything that my app requires with USB and WiFi, and then stop the process I started and read the logs in a file?

Comment: Since logs are stored on the device, you should be able to just capture the logs after you stop the process. You do not need `adb logcat` running during the work.

Comment: Yup, thought the same but my device might be producing an insane amount of logs which get lost in the 3 minutes that the phone is disconnected. I might be wrong but I wasn't able to get the old logs. Note, I was adding the `--pid` flag which might only filter future incoming logs.

Comment: I have not used that flag, so I do not know its effects. If you have not done so already, see if you can adjust the Logcat buffer in Developer Options in Settings. On newer versions of Android, you can bump that up to 16MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the Logcat buffer size to 16MB. That gives plenty of time to do whatever you want while the wire is disconnected. You can do this by going to Developer Options -> Log Buffer Sizes.

This works better than the old answer as the formatting of the logs don't depend on the app used for this purpose.

---

Old answer:

I used a logcat app from the Play Store which worked -- it started a foreground service capturing the logs from logcat while my phone was disconnected from my laptop. This was also helpful because I could see these logs in real time by switching to the app.

The particular app I used was [LogcatReader](https://github.com/darshanparajuli/LogcatReader), but ideally any should do.